# "look forward to hearing your decision"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is better (or something else)?

> "I am looking forward to your decision."
>
> "I am looking forward to hearing your decision."
>
> "I am looking forward to hearing from you about your decision."

The context is emails about application to graduate schools and jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than  “I am looking forward to...” write  “I look forward to...”.  With that change made, the second choice becomes

> I look forward to hearing your decision

which I think is preferable to the other choices.  It is better than the first because it is not the decision itself that you await, but hearing the decision.  It is better than the third because in “hearing from you” the words “from you” are superfluous.

Comment: And #2 is pretty much the conventional phrasing.

Comment: But, since this is all emails, how could `hearing` be the appropriate word choice? You only get to see the email and learn their decision or thoughts from it. You don't hear, right?

Comment: @HariHarker, indeed, most email is read rather than heard aloud.  However, in [en.wiktionary's entry for *hear*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hear#Verb), sense #5  is “To receive information about; to come to learn of”, and that's the applicable sense here.

Comment: @jwpat7 Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense but I wish there was an alternative to convey more precisely as I assume most of them don't read it with the #5 meaning of hear.

Comment: @HariHarker, While many readers may be unaware of that sense of *hear*,  I imagine most will perceive, easily enough, its metaphorical use in “I look forward to hearing your decision”.  Some decisions are communicated verbally, others in writing, with parallel effect.  (The idea of metaphor that I refer to is somewhat like that mentioned in  [an answer of John Lawler on an unrelated topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/104097/11433))