# Looking forward to a reply

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

There are lots of **looking forward to** questions, such as [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13170/look-forward-to-hearing-your-decision).

Can this sentence:

> "I am looking forward to hearing from your reply"

Also be written as:

> "I am looking forward to your reply"

?

Comment: I don't think the title's completely accurate.

Comment: You tagged it with verb, and the title says noun.

Comment: Yes, thats a better title.

Answer (score 6):

We use the second one:

> I am looking forward to your reply.

We don't hear from the reply, we hear from you. What we hear from you is the reply.

Comment: I see, i cannot vote up now, will do, when I have 15 rep.

Comment: Yes, but you can click the check, to choose as best answer. : ) I upvoted you to get you 5 reputation.

Comment: Many will recommend and encourage Questioners to wait at least 24 hr before selecting an answer as "correct". Even if an answer seems complete, this gives the question more "air time" and provides other users the chance to add various perspectives which can provide other primary or secondary information.  Often, this can help "round out" the entire question/answer thread, and can be very illuminating for everyone involved. Also, remember that the philosophy of stack exchange is to provide good question/answers for future readers of this site. So questions with multiple answers is preferred.

Comment: Good point. The problem is, I don't even know when I have time to go on Stack Exchange, so if I asked a question, maybe I come on a week later or something.

Comment: As long as you come back regularly (once a week, once a month), it might be better for you to wait and select a correct answer then, rather than selecting an answer in say, one hour.  There's no particular *rush* to select a correct answer on your part.  Your profile page (access by clicking on your name) will bring up all your history in various ways so you can double check and be sure all your questions have matching answers.  See http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Also, FYI, on this particular "stack" (ell.stackexchange.com), answers with more *votes* are generally considered *more correct* or (perhaps more informative) regardless of which answer is selected correct by the OP.  So if one allows multiple answers, that allows the general community to vote on the best one.

Comment: Yes, I get it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15400/discussion-between-user3724662-and-coolhandlouis).

Answer (score 5):

Here are various options you can use (informal):

- I am looking forward to hearing your reply.
- I am looking forward to hearing from you.
- I am looking forward to your reply.<sup>1</sup>

The following use 'I look' and are more formal versions of the above examples:

- I look forward to hearing your reply.
- I look forward to hearing from you.
- I look forward to your reply.

Note that 'hearing' can refer to written/read communication (letter, email or text). However, I avoid using 'hearing' to refer to  emails. So when I submit a job application, I write 'I look forward to any communication from you ...'.

---

<sup>1. Credit to @user3724662, which is a very good answer.</sup>

Comment: I provided a major edit to your answer which organized it and made it tighter and more focused. Please review. Also, I've explained the reasons for this edit and asked for community members to review my edit here: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/major-edit-to-question-http-ell-stackexchange-com-a-27080-3796

Comment: I'm still new around here, so I'm not sure about the niceties of editing other people's posts (or other people editing mine!). I would very much prefer if people *didn't*. I accept the main part of your edit, but you misunderstood a small part of my final comment. I will use 'hearing' in *my email* if I expect a phone call in reply. I probably won't if I expect an email. So, for job applications, I provide home address, email and phone, but expect an email first or only. It's been a long time since anyone replied to my home address or phone.

Comment: Well to be clear, I have no more authority or privileged status than you. A large revision such as the one I performed is typically beyond the bounds of editing protocol here. Your response is completely acceptable and will be respected. You have absolutely no obligation to accept my edit and every right to roll it back, and anyone here (including me) would back you up and support you 100% on that. And I apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you.

Comment: This answer hits on what I think is the main crux of the O.P.'s question: We can say, "I look forward to hearing **your reply**," or we can say, "I look forward to hearing **from you**," but we ***shouldn't*** say, "I look forward to hearing **from your reply**." To give a second opinion on the more minor point, I don't have a problem with using "hearing" when referring to email, but the point is well-taken. I hadn't thought much about it before, but I suppose that usage could be considered idiomatic.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: I accepted most of your edit. If you think it's necessary, edit away. I can learn things here, too.

Comment: By the way, I have a friend who is blind. She often says things like 'See you next week'. 'See' and 'hear' have meanings beyond purely physical perception.

Comment: "hearing your reply" might be correct, strictly speaking, but it sounds weird.